# How to compare elements of a character array with characters in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I was solving a problem to remove occurrences of given character from the string(CASE-SENSITIVE). Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void func(char a[],char b[])
{
  int i, j = 0;
  char str1[30];
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
  {
    if(a[i] != b[0]){
      str1[j] = a[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  str1[j]='\0';
  printf("%s",str1);
}
int main()
{
    char s[30],c[2];
    scanf("%[^\n]",s);//input string
    scanf("%s",c);//character to remove from string
    func(s,c);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I improve this code(eg: maybe using pointers)? 
I have skipped error-checking for when the character is not in the string for now.

Comment: You have a general idea, but note that `c` is a `char`, and you're passing it into `func` as a `char[]`. Make up your mind.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)` calls `strlen` every time through the loop - very wasteful. When `a` doesn't change. If this code works then it belongs on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) not here.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker `c` is a `char[2]`.

Comment: Ah, so it is. In that case, there's 1000 ways to "improve" the code, most of which are aesthetic judgments.

Comment: If your code works, and all you want is 1000 ways to "improve" it, then you should post the code on [code_review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The question had stated to use pointers to solve it, but I could only do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick.
Study it closely if are just starting out.
I have included some comments to explain what the code is doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void    func(char *s, char c);

int main(void)
    {
    char    s[30], c;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    gets(s);
    printf("Enter char: ");
    c = getchar();

    func(s, c);
    return 0;
    }

void func(char *s, char c)
    {
    char    str1[30], *dp;

    dp = str1;              // point to destination buffer
    while(*s) {             // while not null byte
        if(*s != c)         // if byte != char
            *dp++ = *s++;   // copy to dest buffer
    else
        if(*s == c) {       // if byte == char
            s++;            // bump source pointer
            continue;       // continue till null found
            }
        }
*dp = '\0';             // append null byte to dest
printf("Filtered string: %s\n", str1);
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code !
Also I am attach the screenshot of the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void func(char a[],char b)
{
  int i, j = 0;
  char str1[30];
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
  {
    if(a[i] != b){
      str1[j] = a[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  str1[j]='\0';
  printf("%s",str1);
}
int main()
{
    char s[30],c;
    printf("Enter string :");
    gets(s);//input string
    printf("Enter character that you want to remove :");
    scanf("%c",&c);//character to remove from string
    func(s,c);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]